# Dokan multivendor-Add Custom fields to Registeration

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add 2 custom fields with 15 character input limit to **Dokan Vendor Registeration form**. I am completely new to wordpress and have little coding knowledge on how to do it. I need help in codes which can help me do it.

I refered other forums and changed the Dokan Seller-registeration-form.php to include these fields but they are not getting saved in the Dokan Vendor Profile Settings as well as wordpress backend.

These fields also need to be updated in the Admin Backend in wordpress.

I have tried the link below in stack as solution. 
[Add custom fields to existing form on Dokan (wordpress/woocoomerce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985251/add-custom-fields-to-existing-form-on-dokan-wordpress-woocoomerce).

I am missing something which i have no clue to where it needs to be modified.

I appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Regards
Abhilash

Comment: Please try to break your problem into smaller parts. To ask a question here you need to provide more details, in terms of more general technologies. Please edit your question otherwise someone will downvote it :)

Comment: Hi Ramesh ...thank you for your feedback...this is my first time in such a technical forum. I have edited as per your suggestion. Could you try and help me.

Comment: Abhilash, please clearly tell us what are you trying to do, and what is the problem you are facing when you attempt to do it. For example, instead of talking about a third party plugin like Dokan, which is  less commonly used, tell us what you want to achieve using that plugin. then we shall possibly help you with or without using that plugin.

Comment: what I guess is that probably you are following instructions on a blog about how to add some custom fields to that form. if so,  Now tell us which steps you have done and where did you get stuck. tell us what were you expecting the program to behave like and what is the unexpected that you see.

Comment: also you can enable debug in wordpress and then tell us what errors you see

Comment: Hi Ramesh...sorry for my understanding being wrong. I am trying to Add 2 fields which is mandatory for a vendor to register to my website. These extra fields need to appear while registering if the user selects to register as vendor. I have tried using a recommendation in a forum and i was able to add these extra fields as required. The issue is it is not appearing anywhere in the woocommerce users page where all the other information like address, email id etc are captured except for these newly created fields.

Comment: Hi Ramesh....I have messaged you in Skype...my id is abhilash_viswanathan

Answer (score 1):

Here I am showing how you can add extra field in the registration form. [Not with input limit]
You need a child-theme before doing this process. If you have installed a child theme already then you can override the seller registration form through it.
Please create a folder called dokan into your child-theme and then create another folder into dokan folder called global. Now, copy the seller-registration-form.php file from your wp-content/plugins/dokan-lite/templates/global folder and paste it to your child-theme
[image]

Now, from your child-theme open the seller-registration-form.php file and add the extra field on your desire position like below –
[image]

You can use this code if you want to just copy and paste (Field for GST Number) –

```
<p class="form-row form-group form-row-wide">
    <label for="shop-phone"><?php esc_html_e( 'GST Number', 'dokan-custom-codes' ); ?> 
<span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" name="gst_id" id="gst_id" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $postdata['gst_id'] ) ) echo esc_attr($postdata['gst_id']); ?>" required="required" />
</p>
```

After adding the input field you will be able to see the registration field on the vendor registration form-
[image]

Now, you have to save the field data and need to show on user profile.
Just open your functions.php file and paste the below code –

```
function dokan_custom_seller_registration_required_fields( $required_fields ) {
$required_fields['gst_id'] = __( 'Please enter your GST number', 'dokan-custom' );

return $required_fields;
};

add_filter( 'dokan_seller_registration_required_fields', 
'dokan_custom_seller_registration_required_fields' );


function dokan_custom_new_seller_created( $vendor_id, $dokan_settings ) {
$post_data = wp_unslash( $_POST );

$gst_id =  $post_data['gst_id'];

update_user_meta( $vendor_id, 'dokan_custom_gst_id', $gst_id );
}

add_action( 'dokan_new_seller_created', 'dokan_custom_new_seller_created', 10, 2 );

  /* Add custom profile fields (call in theme : echo $curauth->fieldname;) */ 

add_action( 'dokan_seller_meta_fields', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

<?php if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( ! user_can( $user, 'dokandar' ) ) {
        return;
    }
     $gst  = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'dokan_custom_gst_id', true );
 ?>
     <tr>
                <th><?php esc_html_e( 'Gst Number', 'dokan-lite' ); ?></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="gst_id" class="regular-text" value="<?php 
echo esc_attr($gst); ?>"/>
                </td>
     </tr>
  <?php
 }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_woocommerce' ) ) {
        return;
    }
update_usermeta( $user_id, 'dokan_custom_gst_id', $_POST['gst_id'] );
}
```

If you want to change the field name or meta key then you have to change the meta key or field name accordingly on every place. On this code, I have used the meta key for the field as dokan_custom_gst_id and use the field id as gst_id

After saving the above code, you will be able to use vendor GST Number on his/her user profile –
[image]